# String of 1's & 0's into Raw Data

Tags: java, string, file, binary

I have a web page with random 1's and 0's in the body and I want to treat it as raw binary data and save it to a file.

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
        <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0</pre>
    </body>
</html>
```

Alternatively, I can get the file in one column. If I just url.openStream() and read bytes, it spits out ascii values (49 & 48). I'm also not sure how to write one bit at a time to a file. How do I go about doing this?

Comment: Pedantic aside: what you're describing can't really be called "handling raw binary data" – since you're handling the characters `'1'` and `'0'`;

Comment: Your data compression ratio is 128 (assuming your text encoding is 8-bits/char)... That means that storing 1kb of data in your format "compresses" it to 128kb. Consider reading actual binary data from the filesystem (compression ratio of 1). You'd also avoid a ton of bit shifting and ORing when you read the data into actual binary data...

Comment: @Robert Rouhani you just restated exactly what I'm trying to do, I can't read from the page in binary. It will only give me ascii values. How do I read the text as binary data? With a BufferedReader I can't even split the line with " " it just gives me one entry array with the entire line.

Comment: @user1684045 Why are you reading from the page in the first place? A file upload control would be easier.

Comment: why does everyone assume I can get into the file system? All I can obtain is exactly what I described, a page with ascii 1's and 0's ...

Comment: No, what I'm saying is that you shouldn't be storing your "binary" data like that. Store it in an actual file on disk and use use a language that can actually [read from the filesystem.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)

Comment: @RobertRouhani I don't think OP has write access to that server.

Comment: @user1684045 Because it's a perfectly sane assumption to make. If your use case involves unusual constraints either mention them up front or take it in stride when people don't intuit them right away.

Comment: Try encoding in [base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) then. A quick google search will reveal Javascript snippets for encoding/decoding to base64.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <pre style="word-wrap: break-word; white-space: pre-wrap;">1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0</pre>

This can be sent as two (base64) or three (hex) bytes, so I am assuming efficiency isn't an issue here. ;)  Once you extract the String you can convert it with.

```
String s = "1 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 0";
long l = Long.parseLong(s.replaceAll(" ", ""), 2);
```

Comment: This will parse up to 63-bits no problem, if you need more use `BigInteger`

Answer (score 0):

You can read bits into byte and then write bytes to a file:

```
int byteIndex = 0;
int currentByte = 0;
while (hasBits) {
    String bit = readBit();
    currentByte = currentByte << 1 | Integer.valueOf(bit);
    if (++byteIndex == 8) {
        writeByte(currentByte);
        currentByte = 0;
        byteIndex = 0;
    }
}

// write the rest of bits here
```

Also I agree with Robert Rouhani, this is very inefficient way to transfer data.